# Full upgrade window pops up every hour every hour on Lubuntu

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, update-manager

I updated my system 3 days ago, and since then the update window pops up every hour.

I don't want to update the system regularly. It is very annoying, while working.

How to turn the popup window off?

Comment: Why do you call it a "Full upgrade" window? The term "full upgrade" has a specific meaning. Is your use of that term intentional?

Comment: In Preferences > Software Sources, how often are you set to automatically check for updates? It shouldn't be going off every hour, so long as you're up to date. You can change the update check frequency by rummaging around in there.

Comment: It's set on daily, and ticked on install updates automatically. But still for some reason it doesn't automatically updates the system.

Comment: The update notifier (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.4/Update-Notifier.html) is a Lubuntu created tool (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-update-notifier). You can find it auto-starting in LXQt Session Settings (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html) and you can disable it from there.  I would likely jump to terminal first, and enter `sudo apt update` to ensure valid messages only show, no warnings etc, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` to check it completes without warnings/errors. Warnings/errors maybe reason for constant prompts so I'd fix them

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I turned autostart off and did the `apt update` and `full upgrade` now it's not popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update notifier https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.4/Update-Notifier.html

is a Lubuntu created tool https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-update-notifier.

You can find it auto-starting in LXQt Session Settings and you can disable it from there.

In the Lubuntu manual, you'll find it at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html

I would still jump to terminal first, and enter

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

to ensure valid messages only show, no warnings/errors on either command. Warnings/errors maybe the reason for constant prompts so I'd fix any warnings/errors before I disabled the notifier.